# prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}n!\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{k!} = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can someone help me with a proof that
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}~n!\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{k!} = 0$?
It would be great if the proof could avoid using the gamma function.

This limit is an intermediate value in a larger proof.  It is a lemma necessary in my proof that the Laplacian expansion algorithm of an $n
\times n$ matrix has complexity $(e-1)n!$.
The actual value of the complexity is
$T(n) = n!\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k!}$.
The summation term is the leading part of an infinite sum which converges to $e$.   If we add and subtract $e$ we end up with $T(n) = n!\Big(e - 1\Big) - n!\Big(\displaystyle\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\Big)$.
The question posted here, is to show that the term being subtracted is asymptotically zero.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\prod_{l=1}^k(n+l)}\leq\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\prod_{l=1}^kn}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^k}=\frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{n-1}.$$
Now you can use the squeeze lemma to prove your limit. I believe you can finish it now.
The tricky part to "justify" in one's head should be clear with this:
$$\frac{1}{k!}=\frac{1}{\prod_{t=1}^kt}=\frac{1}{\prod_{t=1}^nt\prod_{t=n+1}^kt}=\frac{1}{n!\prod_{t=n+1}^kt}=\frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{\prod_{t'=1}^{k-n}(n+t')},$$
assuming $k>n$, where in the last step we substituted $t'=t-n$. Now we will use the substitution $k'=k-n$ to derive the whole thing:
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{\prod_{t'=1}^{k-n}(n+t')}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{\prod_{t'=1}^{k-n}(n+t')}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k'=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\prod_{t'=1}^{k'}(n+t')}.$$
Now just rename $t'$ and $k'$ back to $l$ and $k$.

Comment: I get it that it's a bit cumbersome. Please try calculating the first few terms of that sum.

Comment: @JimNewton I edited the queston. Is it clear now?